# DATE_FORMAT in where condition of Codeigniter Active Record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want the Codeigniter equivalent of the sql below:

```
select * from `table_name` where DATE_FORMAT('table_name', "%Y-%m") < "YYYY-MM"
```

I have tried it but get NULL as the answer.Here is how i did it

```
$this->db->select_sum('column_name')->from('table_name')->where("DATE_FORMAT('column_name','%Y-%m') <","YYYY-MM")->get();
```

Thnx for any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use without quotes `column_name` like `DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%Y-%m')`

```
$this->db->select_sum('column_name')
         ->from('table_name')
         ->where("DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%Y-%m') <","YYYY-MM")
         ->get();
```

Comment: It's possible an alias on where("DATE_FORMAT ... ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $this->db->select_sum('column_name')
          ->from('table_name')
          ->where("DATE_FORMAT('column_name','%Y-%m') < YYYY-MM")
          ->get();
```

You can write your own clauses manually in where... [read the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: I get the answer when there is no quotes around the column name inside the date_format function...infact that will correct the problem i initially had in the question...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(your_date_field, 'Year: %Y Month: %m Day: %d') AS formated_date");
$query = $this->db->get('your_table');
```

you just go through this [THREADS](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/74206/#368777)